# IndexError: string index out of range - with len()

Tags: python, string

I'm currently trying to make a simple code (basically mad-libs) and I made a variable called `time`. The user is supposed to type in something like months or days. If a user inputs month or day, an `if` statement is supposed to add an `"s"` to make it plural:

```
time = str(input("Pick a measurement of time (ex. days): "))
if time[len(time)] != "s":
   time = time + "s"
```

When I test this code out, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/nikis_staff/PROGRAMMING/madlibs.py", line 51, in <module>
      if time[len(time)] != "s":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I know that `string index out of range` means the string is longer than I thought it was but I am using `len()`.

Comment: More idiomatic: `if not time.endswith("s"):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes in Python [begin with 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zero-based_numbering&oldid=695682632), i.e. the first element in a string, list, tuple, etc. is: `0`. Hence the last element of `s` is `len(s)-1`. So `time[len(time)]` addresses the element after the last element, which of course causes an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError). Use `time[len(time) - 1]` instead, or better yet: `time[-1]`.

Often you will find [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) `s[-1:]` helpful, too, because it returns `''` for an empty string instead of raising an IndexError.

C.f. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: You're welcome! Next to all programming languages have zero-based indexes. Of the languages I know only Pascal/Delphi and Matlab use 1-based indexes. The rationale is that the calculation is much easier to do in a 0-based system.

Answer (score 2):

If a string is of length 5, like `'hello'`, then the max index is `4` since indexing is zero-based (starts from 0, not 1).

```
>>> len('hello')
5
>>> 'hello'[4]
'o'
```

You can avoid calculating the length by using relative offsets for the index. So, if you want the last character, use -1, like this:

```
>>> 'hello'[-1]
'o'
```

Answer (score -1):

The right code is:

`time = str(input("Pick a measurement of time (ex. days): "))
if time[len(time) - 1] != "s":
   time = time + "s"`

The length of `time` is `len(time)`, but the largest index of `time` is `len(time) - 1` since the index starts from zero.

Or you can just use `if time[-1] != "s":` to get and judge the tail element.

Comment: Could you tell me why if you think my answer is not useful?